# Data didn't show up on API PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I'm a newbie in PHP and I try to get a lyric using an API. I have a problem with my code because the data didn't show up but there is no error message appear. Here my code :

```
$url3 = file_get_contents("http://lyric-api.herokuapp.com/api/find/". urlencode($artist)."/". urlencode($nm_track));
$json3 = json_decode($url3, true);
$lyrics = $json3['lyric'];
```

Please look the code, i just want to know where is the mistake?

Comment: Just print the $url3 and  check you have the encoded data

Comment: print_r($json3) to see result

Comment: can you provide a full url ?

Comment: I try to used `print_r($json3)` the result is `Array ( [lyric] => [err] => not found )`

Comment: here is the full url http://lyric-api.herokuapp.com/api/find/queen/bohemian%20rhapsody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT/UPDATE: if there are any spaces in the artist / song, you should use `rawurlencode($artist). "/" . rawurlencode($nm_track)` so that spaces get translated into `%20` and not `+` as `urlencode()` does.

```
<?php
$artist='queen';
$nm_track='bohemian rhapsody';
echo rawurlencode($artist) . "/" . rawurlencode($nm_track);
$url3 = file_get_contents("http://lyric-api.herokuapp.com/api/find/". rawurlencode($artist). "/" . rawurlencode($nm_track));
$json3 = json_decode($url3, true);

$lyrics = $json3['lyric'];
echo $lyrics;
```

output:
Is this the real life? Is this just fantasy? ...

if you also want to first test for errors(artist / song data not available), you can check out element `$json3['err']`.